# git clone no longer a repo, how do I fix this?

Tags: git, github

I cloned a repo and then moved it up a directory and that somehow removed it from being a repo. How do I fix this so that I can push the once repo back up to where I got it from?

Comment: I suspect that when you moved it, you failed to move the .git folder at the root of the repository.

Comment: Can you explain yourself better. Did you meant you want to push what you cloned as a repo to a place where was the repo you removed?

Comment: Moving a git repo from one directory to other directory doesn't remove it from being a git repo. At least it didn't happen with me just now. Did you accidently delete your .git folder?

Comment: Note that the `.git` folder is hidden by default. So if you just move the contents of the folder in a graphical interface you might have missed it.

Comment: i moved it in command line i did, mv gitrepo/* .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing a "mv gitrepo/* .",you did not move the gitrepo/.git directory with the rest of your directory structure. The * wildcard will not match against .* on the command line so it would not have seen the .git directory (or any other .files inside gitrepo/.

If you still have the original directory you moved stuff from, you could find the .git directory there and move it to the new repo directory.
For instance,

```
mv gitrepo/.git newrepolocation/.git
```

If you removed the old gitrepo directory after you finished moving stuff out of it, you will need to make a new clone of the origin repo, and then move the .git directory from the new clone into newrepolocation/.

Comment: He probably wants `(shopt -s dotglob; mv gitrepo/* .)` to be sure he got all the dotfiles.